# Save quote in same order as cart details show on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

I have selected a bundle product with 5 options say a,b,c,d,e. On cart details it appears in same order but if I check sales_flat_quote_item table ,order of bundle options gets changed let's say a,d,b,e,c. That's why when I place the order , order of options  in sales_flat_order_item also appears same as quote order.

And when I see that product in a`dmin sales->orders`, order appears to be disturbed as saved in `sales_flat_order_item`.

I want to show the order of bundled options same as it appeared on cart details before placing order.